# Refresh OAuth Token in Spring boot OAuth2RestOperations

Tags: spring-boot, salesforce, spring-cloud, spring-security-oauth2, spring-oauth2

I am using Spring Boot Cloud OAuth client to connect with Salesforce restapi. However I am getting `Session expired or invalid` error. Is there anyway to refresh token I was under the assumption that Spring Boot handles this automatically under the hood but seems like that is not the case. Here is the relevant code.

```
@Configuration
public class SalesforceConfiguration {

    @Value("${salesforce.tokenUrl}")
    private String tokenUrl;

    @Value("${salesforce.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Value("${salesforce.clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Value("${salesforce.username}")
    private String username;

    @Value("${salesforce.password}")
    private String password;

    @Bean
    protected OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource() {

        ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resource = new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();

        resource.setAccessTokenUri(tokenUrl);
        resource.setClientId(clientId);
        resource.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        resource.setClientAuthenticationScheme(AuthenticationScheme.form);
        resource.setUsername(username);
        resource.setPassword(password);

        return resource;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestOperations restTemplate() {

        OAuth2RestTemplate operations = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource(), new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));
        operations.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
        operations.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        return operations;
    }
}
```

and this is how I am using it in service.

```
@Component
public class QueryExecutor extends AbstractExecutor implements SalesforceExecutor {

    private OAuth2RestOperations restOperations;

    public QueryExecutor(OAuth2RestOperations restOperations) {

        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public Response process(Request request) throws Exception {

        JsonNode jsonNode = restOperations.getForObject(buildUrl(request), JsonNode.class);

        return new Response<>(ResponseCode.SUCCESS_GET.getCode(), jsonNode, request.getResponseHandler());
    }

    private String buildUrl(Request request) {

        return new StringBuilder().append(getServiceUrl(restOperations))
                                  .append("/services/data/v41.0/query/?q=")
                                  .append(request.getPayload().get("query"))
                                  .toString();
    }
}
```

Is there anyway to refresh token seamlessly using this approach if I get session expired error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright finally after days of debugging I think I found the solution of this issue. This is how I was able to resolve it. I am putting the solution here so that others can benefit from it.

```
@Component
public class QueryExecutor implements SalesforceExecutor {

    private OAuth2RestOperations restOperations;

    public QueryExecutor(OAuth2RestOperations restOperations) {

        this.restOperations = restOperations;
    }

    @Override
    public Response process(Request request) throws Exception {

        try {

            JsonNode jsonNode = restOperations.getForObject(buildUrl(request), JsonNode.class);

            return new Response<>(ResponseCode.SUCCESS_GET.getCode(), jsonNode, request.getResponseHandler());

        } catch (HttpClientErrorException | HttpServerErrorException e) {

            if (HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED.value() == e.getStatusCode().value()) {

                restOperations.getOAuth2ClientContext().setAccessToken(this.getRenewedToken(restOperations.getResource()));
            }

            // retry again with renewed token
        }
    }

    private String buildUrl(Request request) {

        return "someurl";
    }

    private OAuth2AccessToken getRenewedToken(OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails resource) {

        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(resource, new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(new DefaultAccessTokenRequest()));

        return oAuth2RestTemplate.getOAuth2ClientContext().getAccessToken();
    }
}
```

Thats it.

Answer (score 1):

Using Spring Boot, you shouldn't need the entire `SalesforceConfiguration` configuration class.

You can use the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-autoconfigure</artifactId>
     <version>${look-for-the-latest}</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2-client</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Add the configuration properties to your `application.yml`:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      username: the-username
      password: the-password
      client-id: the-client-id
      client-secret: the-client-secret
      grant-type: password,refresh_token
      scope: read
      access-token-uri: http://sales-force-domain/oauth/token
```

And then you can define your `OAuth2RestTemplate` like this:

```
    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate(final OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails details) {
        return new OAuth2RestTemplate(details);
    }
```

To use it just do how you're already doing, inject the `OAuth2RestTemplate` in the `QueryExecutor`. The refresh token will be handled by Spring once you defined it as a `grant-type` in the `application.yml`.

[In this repo](https://github.com/marcosbarbero/spring-security-oauth2-client), I've got a working version of this configuration, bear with me because it also demonstrates how to manually create this configuration.

Comment: Thank you I will try this. However does is take care of token refresh/session timeout?

Comment: That's the whole point of using Spring :) it does take care of it for you, it's just a matter of setting it up correctly. If you do set the grant_type to `refresh_token` along with the type you need, it will do the trick

Comment: If it works for you and you could tag my answer as the correct one, I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Sadly that did not work I am getting `Unable to obtain a new access token for resource 'null'. The provider manager is not configured to support it.` which I was not getting before.

Comment: Can you share some code? A public repo would be the best

Comment: Ok I found the problem. I am using Salesforce OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow in which it does not send refresh tokens. Is there anyway to refresh access token without using refresh token. Re-initializing OAuth2RestOperations bean or something.

Comment: You've to add `refresh_token` grant to your configuration and it should fix your problem, that's what I was trying to point on the `application.yml` snippet above.

Comment: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm

Comment: @nicholasnet I am afraid I'm not following what you're saying. What I'm trying to say is, you can use both of the grant_types together. The password grant_type and the refresh_token together. SalesForce supports the refresh token grant (I use it here in the company) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_refresh_token_flow.htm&type=0

Comment: Yes you are right Salesforce does send `refresh_token` but it does not send one in `OAuth 2.0 Username-Password Flow` which is one what I am using because it is server to server communication without manual intervention.

Comment: Username-password flow allows you to have a refresh token grant configure together with it, however, if what you need server to server communication you need client credentials flow instead of the username one.

Comment: Client credential flow? It is not listed here. https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_authenticate_overview.htm
Would you please share more information regarding this flow if you can. Thank you.

Comment: This other document mentions it https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-s2s-client-credentials.htm

Comment: That documentation does not mentions anything about refresh token though. But I will keep looking. In the meantime I was able to solve this problem using re-authentication...solution I will post shortly.

Comment: Client Credentials flow doesn't support refresh_token, the point is mainly on what is the correct flow to be used given the use-case. In your use-case a Client Credentials Flow is preferred as it's just Server to Server communication. Using a username-password flow doesn't fit well on your use-case because there's no actual user involved.

Comment: @MarcosBarbero salesforce returns refresh_token and expiration info as null and I am guessing that 401 unauthorized exception is because of that.